# Firebase Dynamic Links No Longer Open App

Tags: swift, entitlements, firebase-dynamic-links, applinks

I am working on an app that uses Firebase dynamic links.  All throughout testing, the base link, and deep links would open the app, as expected.

At some point, this stopped working on my test device.  I tried turning the Associated Domains off and back on again (format is applinks:myappid.app.goo.gl).  My URL Types setup in Info has the URL scheme set to my app's bundle id, which is also reflected in Firebase.  My AASA still has the expected info in it as well.

I also tried long pressing on the link in both notes and messages (don't get an option to open in app, just open), but it still refuses to work.  Oddly enough, it still works in simulator.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** I uploaded the build to TestFlight, and it works properly there.  It looks like the issue only occurs on a physical test device, with the app being built from XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Update:** Oddly enough after installing a dynamic links build via TestFlight, subsequent XCode test run builds started working properly again.  Not the most elegant solution, but at least it is working now.

**Update:**
This most likely has to do with an open issue that prevents the AASA file from being updated or installed.  Currently the only work around is to delete the app, reboot the device, and reinstall.

http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4999496467480576